# Weird black line above DialogFragment AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

I have a screenshot below of a random dark/black slightly downwards gradient line appearing above my dialog fragments.

These are build with a dialogfragment class that has been overridden, and an alertdialog builder is being used to construct them (happens with and without the title/buttons) inside the following method

*public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)*

Anyone had this happen to them before or have any ideas?

Ive tried to theme them differently, and the same happens with both API14 holo and holoeverywhere library. Ive tried to set the backgrounds to transparent ect... but havent achieved anything except making the dim go away.

[image: Dark lin]

Comment: try turning off drop shadows and that kind of thing. 

Its tricky you might need to showsome code

Comment: It was a drop shadow, but i couldn't find access to it through styles or anything, see answer i posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way of getting around my problem.

So the deal was that the FrameLayout (with id: android:id/content) that the system makes itself had a foreground drawable on it (the shadow at the top of the frame). I couldnt for the life of me deal with it with styles or anything, nor could i figure out why it was happening on these two custom alert dialogs inside dialogfragments.

note: im using a HoloEverywhere fork thats compatible with v7 AppCompat, but keeping as many of the classes ect... from the actual support libraries.

I could however access the framelayout and remove the foreground drawable with this:
(note: it had to be in the onresume as i dont think there are any calls before that resulted in a "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content" error.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((FrameLayout) getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).setForeground(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

If theres a better safer way of doing this, or if anyone knows why this is happening, let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add your custom theme for your dialog and provide `android:windowContentOverlay` parameter.

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your `DialogFragment` in `onCreate` call:

```
setStyle(/* desired style */, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Simple and powerful solution.  It works.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The Weird Line appears because of the title bar. You just need to hide the title bar and it automatically hides the weird line:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // request a window without the title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // make your dialog here
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 private Dialog custom_dialog;
 private Window window;
 custom_dialog = new Dialog(context);
 custom_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 custom_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.share_dialog);
 custom_dialog.setCancelable(true);
//Below code is used to remove wired black line
 window = custom_dialog.getWindow();
 window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.empty);
```

Comment: Could you provide an answer in your own words or add an explanation of the code, please? Code example should be just an addition to your answer, not a complete answer. It should help users to understand the problem and to prevent them to just copy&paste the code without thinking.